# Separate "below of nodes" in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, overleaf

I have the following code

```
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \tikzstyle{comp1} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm, 
  fill=gray!50] 
  \tikzstyle{comp2} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm] 
  \tikzstyle{comp3} = [draw, ellipse, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm, fill=gray!10, text centered]

  \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm]

%%% NODES %%%
\node (dataset)     [comp1]         {Dataset};
\coordinate[below of=dataset] (c);
\node (train)         [comp2, left of=c]      {Train};
\node (test)        [comp2, right of=c]     {Test};
\coordinate[below of=train] (d);
\node (train_train)       [comp3, left of=d]     {Train};
\node (train_validation)  [comp3, right of=d] {Validation};
\coordinate[below of=test] (e);
\node (test_train)       [comp3, left of = e]  {Train};
\node (test_validation)  [comp3, right of = e ] {Validation};
%%% ARROWS %%%
\draw [arrow] (dataset) -- (train);
\draw [arrow] (dataset) -- (test);
\draw [arrow] (train) -- (train_train);
\draw [arrow] (train) -- (train_validation);
\draw [arrow] (test) -- (test_train);
\draw [arrow] (test) -- (test_validation);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Which results in this:

[image: diagram]

When I need it to be:

```
>              Dataset
>      train             test 
>  train validation  train validation
```

I know Test and Validation from the 3rd level are overlapped, because I'm using a relative coordination of the 2nd level, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

To solve your problem I just specify the node distance for Train and Test nodes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\tikzstyle{comp1} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm, fill=gray!50] 
\tikzstyle{comp2} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm] 
\tikzstyle{comp3} = [draw, ellipse, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm, fill=gray!10, text centered]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm]
  %%% NODES %%%
  \node (dataset)     [comp1]         {Dataset};
  \coordinate[below of=dataset] (c);
  \node (train)         [comp2, left =3.75cm of c]      {Train};
  \node (test)        [comp2, right =3.75cm of c]     {Test};
  \coordinate[below of=train] (d);
  \node (train_train)       [comp3, left of=d]     {Train};
  \node (train_validation)  [comp3, right of=d] {Validation};
  \coordinate[below of=test] (e);
  \node (test_train)       [comp3, left of = e]  {Train};
  \node (test_validation)  [comp3, right of = e ] {Validation};
  %%% ARROWS %%%
  \draw [arrow] (dataset) -- (train);
  \draw [arrow] (dataset) -- (test);
  \draw [arrow] (train) -- (train_train);
  \draw [arrow] (train) -- (train_validation);
  \draw [arrow] (test) -- (test_train);
  \draw [arrow] (test) -- (test_validation);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry! will do my code compilable next time, didn't think about it. This solution worked great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using `forest`. You can adjust horizontal spacing (`s sep`) or vertical spacing (`l sep`) however you wish.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={draw, thick, edge={thick, -stealth}, s sep=1cm, l sep=1cm, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm,
    if n children=0 
        {ellipse, fill=gray!10} % if it's a leaf
        {rounded corners}} % otherwise...
[Dataset, fill=gray!50
    [Train
        [Train][Validation]
    ]
    [Test
        [Train][Validation]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a second approach for you, using the tikz library `shapes.geometric` and `xshift`. The partial `grid` is for orientation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}% <<< contains ellipses
 
 
\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{comp1} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm, fill=gray!50] 
    \tikzstyle{comp2} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm] 
    \tikzstyle{comp3} = [draw, ellipse, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm, fill=gray!10, text centered]

  \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]



\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm]
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (5, -5);% just to indicate coordinates

    %%% NODES %%%
    \node (dataset) [comp1]         {Dataset};
    \coordinate[below of=dataset] (c);
    \node (train)   [comp2, left of=c,  xshift=-2cm]    {Train};% using xshift
    \node (test)    [comp2, right of=c, xshift= 2cm]    {Test};%  same
    
    \coordinate[below of=train] (d);
    \node (train_train)       [comp3, left of=d]     {Train};
    \node (train_validation)  [comp3, right of=d] {Validation};
    \coordinate[below of=test] (e);
    \node (test_train)       [comp3, left of = e]  {Train};
    \node (test_validation)  [comp3, right of = e ] {Validation};
    %%% ARROWS %%%
    \draw [arrow] (dataset) -- (train);
    \draw [arrow] (dataset) -- (test);
    \draw [arrow] (train) -- (train_train);
    \draw [arrow] (train) -- (train_validation);
    \draw [arrow] (test) -- (test_train);
    \draw [arrow] (test) -- (test_validation);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```